# C# Net Core - Run application with administrator permission in Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, .net-core

I'm trying to run my application on Ubuntu 22.04 with Net Core 7, but I'm having serious permission issues.

When I try to run **./App** I get the error:

> -bash: ./App : Permission denied

Trying to run **sudo -E ./App** I get the error:

> sudo: ./App: command not found

If I give permission to the file with the command **sudo chmod 777 /home/ubuntu/App**, I can run application with **sudo -E ./App**.

But, the application is not running with administrator permissions, if I try to read and write files and folders, for example, I get the Exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/home/ubuntu/test/' is denied.
  ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
```

How do I run an application published for Linux x64 as an administrator?

*I've already looked for other topics that recommended trying using script, bash, nohup, among others, but I wasn't successful either.*

---

**Update:** I compiled and sent the files in .dll format, ran them with the command **sudo dotnet App.dll** and it's working perfectly. The **sudo -E** command is not giving the admin permission.

Comment: Strange thing. Let's start with the obvious: Does `/home/ubuntu/test/` exist?

Comment: Note that the chmod is required if you copy an app from a Windows to a Linux box, so that part is to be expected.

Comment: Yes, **/home/ubuntu/test/** exist.

Comment: What exactly are you trying? Can you debug to find the line causing the error? Maybe you attempt to delete the folder when there are still open files, or something like that.

Comment: `sudo bash ./App`